# Raspbian with a VLAN setup, assigning 2 IP addresses to each interface when I don't want it to

Tags: debian, raspbian, vlan

I can't figure this out. Below is my configuration in /etc/network/interface.d/eth0. Originally I had all these setup as DHCP, but I was getting 2 IPs for each interface. I changed it to static and I am still getting 2 IPs per interface. I have rebooted and it usually results in multiple IPs. If I just 'ifup eth0' it will have a single IP, however once I ifup the other 2 it will assign IPs to the other ones as well.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.111
        gateway 192.168.1.1

auto eth0.2
iface eth0.2 inet static
        address 172.16.1.111
        gateway 172.16.1.1

auto eth0.3
iface eth0.3 inet static
        address 192.168.124.111
        gateway 192.168.124.1
```

This is a Raspbian Lite install.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote the words "This is a Raspbian Lite install." I realised an assumption I made, I assumed I was using Debian and not Raspbian. This configuration works in Debian but in Raspbian you need to do the following:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth0.2
iface eth0.2 inet manual

auto eth0.3
iface eth0.3 inet manual
```

By default, these interfaces will be configured by DHCPCD. You can assign static IP addresses  by adding the to the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file.